# Android - could not execute method of the activity

Tags: android

I have a service library with a broadcast receiver in it.

All I am doing in my main application is calling certain methods within the service, nothing new there.

I am receiving the following everytime I want to run my code (please look below)

**Error**

```
02-21 15:51:26.721  31125-31125/com.haswell.phoneduplicator E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.haswell.phoneduplicator, PID: 31125
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3969)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3964)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:94)
        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:114)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:272)
        at com.haswell.wifidirectlibrary.wifiDirectService.toastme(wifiDirectService.java:99)
        at com.haswell.wifidirectlibrary.wifiDirectService.peerSearch(wifiDirectService.java:151)
        at com.haswell.phoneduplicator.sendActivity.authenticateClick(sendActivity.java:52)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3964)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**The service - please note below this is more code which is not working**

public void checkWifi() {

```
    toastme("reached peerSearch");
//check if wifi is on

//ERROR HERE ---------------------------------------------
//how can this be null as it is boolean?
if (!isWifiP2pEnabled) {

    //peerSearchError =  "Wifi is off!";

    return;
}
```

}

**the isWifiP2pEnabled is a method which gets called from the broadcast receiver upon discovering the state of wifi**

```
public void setIsWifiP2pEnabled(boolean WifiP2pEnabled) {

    isWifiP2pEnabled = WifiP2pEnabled;
}
```

**This is not all of the broadcast receiver but here is where it is calling the method above..**

```
if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {

    activity.toastme("wifi is enabled..");
    // Wifi Direct mode is enabled
    activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(true);
} else {
    activity.toastme("wifi is not enabled..");
    activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(false);

}
```

I am not sure what is going on and why it is not doing it, running through it, it check if wifi is on, it then sets **isWifiP2pEnabled** successfully  which is strange... Am I doing something wrong with **!isWifiP2pEnabled** ?

**TOASTME as requested**

```
public void toastme(String s){
   Toast a;
    a = Toast.makeText(this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    a.show();

}
```

**AuthenticateClick where wifiService is being called**

```
public void authenticateClick(View v) {

    wifiService.peerSearch();

    if (wifiService.peers != null) {
        peers = wifiService.peers;
    }

    Toast s = Toast.makeText(this, peers.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    s.show();

}
```

Please note, the service is being initialized onCreate (Also the service gets created, and is running during this)

Comment: `toastme()` is trying to use an uninitialized `Context`. Since we do not have the code to `toastme()`, or anything else in `wifiDirectService` that `toastme()` depends upon, it will be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: @CommonsWare added, please find it above.

Comment: @KurdishDroid: means trying to call `toastme` method  by creating object of class which is extending Activity?

Comment: The thing is why is that causing a issue? I have used the toastme() within other parts and they work fine..,

Comment: Assuming that `wifiDirectService` is a `Service`, you are calling `toastme()` before the `Service` has been properly initialized. If `sendActivity` is an `Activity`, and `authenticateClick()` is a method on that activity, it should not have access to an instance of `wifiDirectService` on which to call `toastme()`. Moreover, it does not *need* an instance of `wifiDirectService` to raise a `Toast`, as an activity can do that itself. So, where is `sendActivity` getting its instance of `wifiDirectService` from?

Comment: @CommonsWare so is it possible to call a method of a service? (obviously the service is created and running..)

Comment: "so is it possible to call a method of a service?" -- an activity can bind to a service and call methods on the `Binder` supplied by a service. Anything else is a code smell. So, I will ask again, this time in boldface: **where is `sendActivity` getting its instance of `wifiDirectService` from?**

Comment: @CommonsWare by doing the following first, at the top declaring the service    '//Instantiate The Library Class
    wifiDirectService wifiService = new wifiDirectService();' 
then starting the service using and intent on the oncreate of sendActivity '        //Start wifi direct service
        Intent i = new Intent(this, wifiService.getClass());
        startService(i);'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> at the top declaring the service '//Instantiate The Library Class wifiDirectService wifiService = new wifiDirectService();'

**NEVER** create an instance of a `Service` yourself. Delete this line from your code, along with all references to `wifiService`.

If you wish to raise a `Toast`, that is fine, but **use a `Context` that was created by the framework and was handed to you**. If an activity wishes to raise a `Toast`, the activity itself is a great `Context` to use for this purpose.

If you really wish to have your activity call methods on your service, you need to [use the binding pattern and bind to the service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#CreatingBoundService).

Comment: Yes will this be the case if the service is in a library which is the whole reason I am creating this.. would that matter?

Comment: @KurdishDroid: "will this be the case if the service is in a library" -- yes. "would that matter?" -- no.

Comment: perfect, I will switch to this now... thanks so much for your help! :)

Comment: Sorry one more question, will I still be able to use onCreate and other events as before on the normal unbound services?

Comment: @KurdishDroid: `onCreate()` still gets called. `onStartCommand()` only gets called in response to `startService()`, though.

Comment: but im presuming startService() gets called when you bind to the service? actually no worries i understand now, i can just move all the onStartCommand to onBind... ok perfect only issue I am having atm is if all of this is exactly what I need to create my app... I am trying to figure out if this is the right move.. to create a service library which will connect to a broadcast receiver.. (this can then be used by others to use certain features such as search for peers) ..

Comment: @KurdishDroid: No. `startService()` and `bindService()` are independent patterns, and only infrequently are they used together. "I am trying to figure out if this is the right move.. to create a service library which will connect to a broadcast receiver.. (this can then be used by others to use certain features such as search for peers)" -- I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: I am just wondering by calling this service which in return will create another service (broadcast receiver) will this work ha!

Comment: @KurdishDroid: " which in return will create another service (broadcast receiver)" -- a `BroadcastReceiver` is not a `Service`.

Answer (score 1):

You are making this call in your `Service`

```
activity.toastme("wifi is enabled..");
```

"activity" is not defined or explained in your question. However, if you have a variable called "activity" in your `Service` it's likely that you are making an invalid call to it in the `Service` - an `Activity` should bind to a `Service` and not hold a reference to it. So your "activity" variable may be non-null, but that does not mean that is has a valid context. Therefore, this line:

```
a = Toast.makeText(this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

probably has a "null" context (and the reference to `this` is not valid)

Comment: Please see changes.. I call the same thing toastme("something") on the onCreate (for the service) and this gets called successfully.. Not sure why i cant do this in my checkWifi()